# Wait hub to execute on method to proceed C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, signalr, integration-testing

I'm making an integration test and want a method to wait until "on method" is called. In C#.
Something like this:

```
public async Task CheckMethod(){
    var hubConnection = GetHubConnection();
    connection.On("OnMethod",async () =>{
        Log("First");
    }
    await connection.InvokeAsync("Subscribe", id);
    // Something to wait then proceed
    Log("Second");
}
```

Comment: What you are stuggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
public async Task CheckMethod()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var hubConnection = GetHubConnection();
    connection.On("OnMethod",() =>
    {
        Log("First");
        tcs.TrySetResult(null); 
    }
    await connection.InvokeAsync("Subscribe", id);
    Log("Second");
    await tcs.Task;
    Log("Third");
}
```

Comment: It's possible to add a timeout?

Comment: Just combine the `tcs.Task` with a timeout cancellation token and `Task.WhenAny`.